# How can i read color from json of following type?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
  "events": [
    [
      1,
      "arun Thakur",
      "04/30/2012 00:00",
      "04/30/2012 00:00",
      1,
      0,
      0,
      "11",
      1,
      "New Delhi",
      ""
    ],
    [
      3,
      "ryurts",
      "05/02/2012 01:30",
      "05/02/2012 04:30",
      0,
      0,
      0,
      "blue",
      1,
      "",
      ""
    ],
    [
      7,
      "Sandeep Singh",
      "05/01/2012 00:00",
      "05/01/2012 01:30",
      0,
      0,
      0,
      "blue",
      1,
      "sadasdasfdg",
      ""
    ],
    [
      9,
      "sadasdsdsa",
      "05/02/2012 00:00",
      "05/02/2012 00:00",
      1,
      0,
      0,
      "yellow",
      1,
      "",
      ""
    ],
    [
      11,
      "Hello World",
      "04/30/2012 00:00",
      "04/30/2012 00:00",
      1,
      0,
      0,
      "",
      1,
      "",
      ""
    ]
  ],
  "issort": true,
  "start": "04/30/2012 00:00",
  "end": "05/06/2012 23:59",
  "error": null
}
```

Comment: Please Structure your code it looks very dirty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of those items don't have colours, and the data is poorly structured, but this appears to be what you want:

```
var json = <your data here>;

for(var i = 0; i < json.events.length; i++) {
    var item = json.events[i];
    console.log(item[7]);
}
```

I'm just printing the colours to the console. Presumably you'll put some more useful code in there instead.